# Test a model property in django using Pytest

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I want to test the output of a model property in django using pytest[pytest-django].

models.py:

```
class TravelFriend(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="travel_friends")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birthdate = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def age(self):
        days_in_year = 365.2425
        age = int((date.today() - self.birthdate).days / days_in_year)
        if age >= 18:
            return "18+"
        else:
            return age
```

basically the property return the age in years or the string '18+' if the age is more than 18

test_models.py:

```
class TestTravelFriend:
    def test_travelfriend(self):
        """The family member is connected to a user and have valid attributes"""

        travel_friend = TravelFriendFactory()

        assert travel_friend is not None
        assert str(travel_friend) == travel_friend.name
        assert travel_friend.user is not None
        assert travel_friend.name is not None
        assert travel_friend.birthdate is not None
        assert travel_friend.age is not None
```

factories.py:

```
class TravelFriendFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = "accounts.TravelFriend"

    user = factory.SubFactory("accounts.tests.factories.CustomUserFactory")
    birthdate = factory.Faker(
        "date_of_birth",
        maximum_age=25,
    )
```

I want to test that the output of the property is correct but if i put an if statement in the test like this

```
        year = -int(travel_friend.birthdate.year - date.today().year)
        if year < 18:
            assert travel_friend.age == year
        else:
            assert travel_friend.age == "18+"
```

but in order to have 100% coverage I need to test this last part of code which I don't think is right (testing the tests, really?!?).. any idea on how to test the property correctly? I've looked into pytest.mark.parametrize without success

need to test the property without adding any more tests on test_models.py

```
---------- coverage: platform darwin, python 3.11.4-final-0 ----------
Name                            Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------------
accounts/forms.py                  26      6    77%   29-36
accounts/models.py                 44      1    98%   59
accounts/tests/test_models.py      28      1    96%   48
-------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                             187      8    96%
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed my problem by changing the code to test a little bit

models.py:

```
@property
def age(self):
    days_in_year = 365.2425
    age = int((date.today() - self.birthdate).days / days_in_year)
    return age
```

test_models.py:

```
    assert travel_friend.age is not None
    days_in_year = 365.2425
    assert travel_friend.age == int((date.today() - travel_friend.birthdate).days / days_in_year)
```

template.html:

```
{% for friend in travel_friends %}
  <li>{{ friend.name }} 
    {% if friend.age >= 18 %}(18+)
    {% else %}({{ friend.age }})
    {% endif %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

no need to get '18+' in the property, better to get in the template